# problem with software center

Tags: software-center

```
2015-12-03 02:02:18,961 - softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.app - INFO - setting up proxy 'None'
2015-12-03 02:02:19,303 - softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.app - INFO - building local database
2015-12-03 02:02:19,303 - softwarecenter.db.pkginfo_impl.aptcache - INFO - aptcache.open()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/software-center", line 130, in <module>
    app = SoftwareCenterAppGtk3(options, args)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/app.py", line 313, in __init__
    self._rebuild_and_reopen_local_db(pathname)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/app.py", line 532, in _rebuild_and_reopen_local_db
    rebuild_database(pathname, debian_sources, appstream_sources)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/update.py", line 1148, in rebuild_database
    cache.open()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/pkginfo_impl/aptcache.py", line 261, in open
    self._cache = apt.Cache(progress)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apt/cache.py", line 107, in __init__
    self.open(progress)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apt/cache.py", line 155, in open
    self._list.read_main_list()
SystemError: E:Malformed line 4 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list (dist parse)
```

help me

Comment: You can disable ( delete ) `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list` , and then try out if that's the only error. ... The google-chrome repo can just be reinstalled later. ... Alternatively, get a better "softwarecenter" : `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install synaptic`

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

Thats delete file that giving you problems with this command:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list
```

Then run theses commands to add Google chrome back to the repository

```
wget -q -O - https://dl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -

sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list'
```

Then run:

```
sudo apt-get update
```